# Adding additionalLibs in Solr Operator 0.5.1

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am using Solr operator in GKE and I am trying to use some custom libs in the cluster for a collection.
According the documentation [Link](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/apache-solr/solr/0.5.1) it's possible to use solrOptions.additionalLibs to the classPath when running Solr

I added the configuration to my helm chart

```
solrOptions:
  additionalLibs: 
    - /var/solr/data/backup-restore/local-backup/lib
```

I can't see the plugins in the plugin list in the solr admin.
And I also added in the solrconfig.xml the lib tags

```
 <lib path="/var/solr/data/backup-restore/local-backup/lib/xjoin-blast-7.2.1-0.1.jar" />
```

Any clue how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered a straightforward solution to this issue.
It's not necessary to include the path in the solrconfig.xml file. Once you've added the path to the 'additionalLibs' tag, simply restart the pods.
In the Solr admin panel, you'll then find the 'plugins' section readily available.

[image]